# Ошибка при выводе данных из JSON Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Имею JSON объект (код ниже), и как только я хочу его распарсить:

```
json = JSON.parse(data);
```

консоль выдает ошибку:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
>       at JSON.parse ()

```js
var data = {
  "categories": [{
    "name": "Мясо",
    "products": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Говядина",
      "price": 93.4,
      "description": "Говяжье мясо"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Свинина",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Свинное мясо"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Курятина",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Куриное мясо"
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Баранина",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Мясо барана"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Рыба",
    "products": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Карась",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Речная рыба"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Форель",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Речная, радужная"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Осетрина",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Морская"
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Короп",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Речной, зеркальный"
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Семга",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Океаническая"
    }, {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Мойва",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Свежемороженная"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Хлебо-булочные",
    "products": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Батон",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Нарезной"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Каравай",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Вкусный"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Калач",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "С кунжутом"
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Булка",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "С маком"
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Рогалик",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "С повидлом"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Ликеро-водочные",
    "products": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Пиво",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Светлое, пастеризованное"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Водка",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Кристально чистая"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Виски",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Крепкое"
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Вино",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Крепленое"
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Коньяк",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Без выдержки"
    }, {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Ром",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "С выдержкой"
    }, {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Ликер",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Сладкий"
    }]
  }]
};

json = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: Спасибо, направили меня в правильное направление..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не нужно использовать `JSON.parse(data);` потому что это объект.
Выводите данные из `data` как из объекта:

```
var obj = data.categories;
//example
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj[0].name);
```

Пример:

```js
var data = {
  "categories": [{
    "name": "Мясо",
    "products": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Говядина",
      "price": 93.4,
      "description": "Говяжье мясо"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Свинина",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Свинное мясо"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Курятина",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Куриное мясо"
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Баранина",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Мясо барана"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Рыба",
    "products": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Карась",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Речная рыба"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Форель",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Речная, радужная"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Осетрина",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Морская"
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Короп",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Речной, зеркальный"
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Семга",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Океаническая"
    }, {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Мойва",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Свежемороженная"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Хлебо-булочные",
    "products": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Батон",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Нарезной"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Каравай",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Вкусный"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Калач",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "С кунжутом"
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Булка",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "С маком"
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Рогалик",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "С повидлом"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Ликеро-водочные",
    "products": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Пиво",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Светлое, пастеризованное"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Водка",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Кристально чистая"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Виски",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Крепкое"
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Вино",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Крепленое"
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Коньяк",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Без выдержки"
    }, {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Ром",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "С выдержкой"
    }, {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Ликер",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Сладкий"
    }]
  }]
};

var obj = data.categories;

//example
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj[0].name);
```